# Imacros script to find text and alert if not found

Tags: javascript, firefox, scripting, imacros

I can extract text and make a msgbox if not found using JS, but i need to know how to do it in imacros.

The javascript that i use is here http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm

```
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
 if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
 var strFound;
 if (window.find) {

  // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

  strFound=self.find(str);
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
   while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
  alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
  return;
 }
 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you should search for your text using the following example iMacros Code:

CODE:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:Passwordsuccessfullychanged. EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=extract.csv

then check the extracted text in "extract.csv" file in your iMacros downloads folder.